# Whether the following are the domain of a partially computable function

Tags: logic, computability

Let $f(x,t)=\begin{cases} 1 \quad \text{if Prime(x) is true
 }\\ 0 \quad \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

Clearly f(x,t) is a computable predicate, since Prime(x) is primitive recursive and definition by cases is also primitive recursive.

Could we say $\{x|(\forall t)f(t,x)\}$ is recursively enumerable(r.e). It is the domain of a partially computable function. Here by partially computable function, I mean a program which computes the function which may or may not halt.

I find whenever a predicate f is computable, we could always say $\{x|(\forall t)f(t,x)\}$ is r.e.  Is this true?

Could someone give a counterexample of a predicate where this is not true?

[How to argue that a set is recursive or recursively enumerable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1598856/how-to-argue-that-a-set-is-recursive-or-recursively-enumerable?rq=1)

Definition of a r.e. 
http://prnt.sc/9lq22b

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function

Comment: You defined $f(x)$ with one input, but then you are using $f(t,x)$ with two inputs. What is $f(t,x)$?  Could you please revise the question to make it more clear and direct?

Comment: Sorry, I have updated it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ be a recursively enumerable set which is not recursive. The complement $\mathbb N\setminus A$ is not recursively enumerable, since a recursively enumerable set with recursively enumerable complement is recursive. Since $A$ is recursively enumerable and nonempty, there is a computable surjection $g:\mathbb N\to A.$ Define a predicate
$$f(t,x)=\begin{cases}
1\text{ if }g(t)\ne x,\\
0\text{ if }g(t)=x.
\end{cases}$$
Then $f(t,x)$ is computable, and $\{x|(\forall t)f(t,x)=1\}=\{x|(\forall t)g(t)\ne x\}=\mathbb N\setminus A$ is not recursively enumerable.

Comment: The link says h(i,x) is not computable. Also how is f(t,x) a predicate here. Do you mean $f(t,x) =1$ if it does not halt within first t steps and 0 otherwise. Could you elaborate more? In the book, I am reading they don't use Turing machines. From what I read now about these, this is just a model of computation.

Comment: Since $f(t,x)$ is a predicate. Aren't both the same. Sorry I forgot to mention that predicates take only 1 if true or 0 if false values.

Comment: Yeah awesome!. Just one small correction,  you conclude $\{x|(\forall t)g(t)\ne x\}$ is not recursively enumerable.